# SearchBar mostra resultado certo, leva ao ViewController errado

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, algoritmo-de-busca, uitableview

Estou montando um app que mostra os gerentes na Page1 e seus respectivos funcionários na Page2. Decidi montar em uma plist e carregar numa TableView, veja:

[image: plist and storyboard]

Para carregar a plist corretamente inseri ao AppDelegate o seguinte código:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
            Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
        }
        return true
}
```

Também tenho essa Estrutura me ajudando com tudo isso:

```
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

        let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
        self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém inseri uma SearchBar que me mostra os resultados corretos, **mas ao tocar em "Suzan Brown", vejo os funcionários de "John Smith"**. Não sei se o erro está na `segue`… Alguém poderia me ajudar? Abaixo, minha TableViewController, sei que há algo errado, mas não sei exatamente o que…

```
class Page1: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
    var isSearching : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isSearching == true {
            return self.employeesSearching.count
        } else {
            return Shared.instance.employees.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        let employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]

        if self.isSearching == true {
            cell.nameLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].name
            cell.positionLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].position
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = employee.name
            cell.positionLabel.text = employee.position
        }

        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if self.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
            self.isSearching = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.isSearching = true
            self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            let searchText = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
            for employee in Shared.instance.employees {

                if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
                    self.employeesSearching.append(employee)
                }
            }
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Na sua função  numberOfRowsInSection troque pra `return isSearching ? employeesSearching.count : Shared.instance.employees.count`

Comment: Na sua função cellForRowAt  `if self.isSearching == true {` é redundante troque para `if isSearching {`

Comment: Neste caso utilizar `self.isSearching` e `isSearching` não traz diferença?

Comment: Nao faz diferencia alguma. Existem exceções mas na maioria das vezes você não precisa especificar self

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver!

Bastava só fazer umas mudanças no `segue`, vou colocar o antes e o depois para fins de comparação:

--- **ANTES** ---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

--- **DEPOIS** ---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowP2" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let employee: Employee
            if isSearching == true && searchBar.text != "" {
                employee = employeesSearching[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
            }
            let destination = segue.destination as? Page2
            destination?.newPage = employee
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque um segue da cell para a outra view. Em seguida de uma olhada no sua função do prepareForSegue. Recomendo criar um classe customizada para o sua celular.

ficando alguma coisa assim:

```
class CustonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var positionLabel: UILabel!

    var employee: Employee? {
        didSet {
            guard let employee = employee else { return }
            nameLabel.text = employee.name
            positionLabel.text = tipoBoleto.descricao
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Voltando para a classe que tem sua tabela, agora você vai colocar os dados do seu prepara for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowP2" {
        if let cell = sender as? CustonTableViewCell, let employee = cell.employee {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? Page2 {
                // Aqui você passa o objeto que esta em sua cell customizada para a outra tela
                vc.employee = employee
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Customizando uma cell você vai conseguir maior controle sobre o que esta sendo apresentado.

Comment: A ideia de customizar a cell é excelente! Pode ter certeza que vou coloca-la em prática. Porém, o seu `…prepare(for segue…` não funciona concomitante com a `searchBar` quando eu toco em um item pesquisado. O que eu fiz abaixo funcionou. Mas obrigado de qualquer forma.